# How to hide or obfuscate the type of OS?

Tags: linux, operating-systems, freebsd

I get the OS type of a remote host by:

- connecting to an open port (`telnet <host> 22`);
- using Nmap (`nmap -A <host>`).

What are techniques and how to hide or change the information about OS? I would like to get answers with respect to GNU/Linux or (and) BSD OS.

Comment: Run it in a VM? What's the point anyway?

Comment: @Gilles most of the attacks are specific to a particular OS so it makes sense to obfuscate it. It doesn't prevent the attack but makes it more difficult for the attacker to find a way to get to your machine

Answer (score 1):

- You can hide from Telnet by changing the welcome banner of each service you're worried about (some of these will be easy to change, others will be hard).
- You can make Nmap's OS detection less reliable by configuring your firewall to drop all packets to closed ports: Nmap works best if it can find both an open port and a closed port to probe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it case by case for any remote service you expose:

- Disable the services you don't use
- Hide the version numbers for the services you use (example for a [PHP server](http://www.sysadminworld.com/2012/hide-the-server-version/))

I assume you are trying to avoid leaking information that your server may not be up-to-date or may be vulnerable to a specific zero-day. At the end of the day this won't do much to protect you, adversaries may just learn whether you're vulnerable by attacking directly.